# Unable to connect to a server via socket from raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, sockets, server, firewall, raspberry-pi4

server.py (on desktop)

```py
import socket
listensocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listensocket.bind(('', 8000))
# Starts server
listensocket.listen(999)
print("Server started at " + socket.gethostname() + " on port " + str(8000))
# Accepts the incoming connection
(clientsocket, address) = listensocket.accept()
print("New connection made!")
while True:
    message = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()  # Gets the incoming message
    print(message)
```

client.py (on raspberry pi 4)

```py
import socket
from time import sleep as sl
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.0.103', 8000))  # Connects to server
for i in range(100000000):
    x = f"Message no = {i}"  # Gets the message to be sent
    s.send(x.encode())  # Encodes and sends message (x)
    sl(0.001)
    print(x)
```

I'm having a server hosted on my desktop and I want to send data as a client from raspberry pi 4(32-bit os) to my PC. But the problem is that my raspberry pi was unable to connect to the server hosted on my PC.

> - Both of the devices are hosted on the same network.
> - Both of the devices has their firewall disabled.
> - I'm connected to raspberry pi from desktop via ssh.

and also note that when I switched the client and server sides(of course after changing the IP address in `client.py`) the code runs fine but I want to send data from my raspberry pi to my desktop and not want to receive data from my desktop to pi.

when I tried to see whether the server is available on my pi or not using the command `netstat -t -l -n`(which I found on a [Raspberry pi forum](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=62108#p461676)) then the output was:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: try `socket.bind(('0.0.0.0',port))`  instead of an empty string ... iirc empty string == localhost

Comment: please can you also explain how it works!

Comment: @JoranBeasley: empty string is documented be the same as INADDR_ANY, i.e. same as 0.0.0.0  - from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-families): *"For IPv4 addresses, two special forms are accepted instead of a host address: '' represents INADDR_ANY, which is used to bind to all interfaces ..."*.

Comment: @Aman: *"when I tried to see whether the server is available on my pi or not using the command netstat -t -l -n(which I found on a Raspberry pi forum) then the output was"* -  which shows that the server is not running on your raspi. But the server is not to run there anyway but on your desktop instead based on your question. So it is unclear what you are trying to show with this command. Check instead what is running on your server.